# Recieved an error while running python manage.py migrate and python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, html, django

**form.py**
*This is my form tab.*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from security_app.models import UserProfileInfo
from django import forms
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('Username','email','password')
class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('portfolio_site','profile_pic')
```

**models.py**
*This is my models tab*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**urls.py**
*This is my urls tab under my app "security_app"*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from security_app import views

app_name = 'security_app'

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register')
]
```

**view.py**
*This is view tab.*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from security_app.forms import UserForm, UserProfileInfoForm
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'security_app/index.html')
def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']
            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()
    return render(request,'security_app/registration.html',
                            {'user_form':user_form,
                             'profile_form':profile_form,
                             'registered':registered})
```

**base.html**
*This is my base tab from which i inherit nav bar to other htmls tab*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Base</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">S N A P P P R R</a></li>
          <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a></li>
          <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'security_app:register' %}">Register</a></li>
          <!-- <li><a class="navbar-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Images</a></li> -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
    {% block body_block %}
    {# Anything outside of this will be inherited if you use extend.#}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**registration.html**
*This is my registration tab for user to register*

```
{% extends "security_app/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block%}

    <div class="jumbotron">
      {% if registered %}
      <h1>Thank you for registering</h1>
      {% else %}
      <h1>Register Here</h1>
      <h3>Fill out the form:</h3>

      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {{ profile_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Register">
      </form>

      {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

**ERROR**
*I face this error while running "python manage.py migrate" and "python manage.py runserver". I don't know why this error is coming up.*

```
(team) C:\Users\ragha\project\security>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "c:\users\ragha\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ragha\project\security\security\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from security_app import views
  File "C:\Users\ragha\project\security\security_app\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from security_app.forms import UserForm, UserProfileInfoForm
  File "C:\Users\ragha\project\security\security_app\forms.py", line 4, in <module>
    class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "C:\Users\ragha\Envs\team\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 267, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (Username) specified for User
```

Comment: check the capitalization of `Username`, should be `username`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fields.py, change row 8 - fields = ('Username','email','password') to fields = (**'username'**,'email','password'). Field names are not capitalized.